# How to check which segment is selected with UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I have an UIImagePicker which when you click on a button is shown though I have recently added an option using segments where you can use the camera though I can't seem to check which segment is selected. This is the code that I have got so far:

```
- (IBAction)addPicture:(id)sender {
    if (_photoControl.selected == 0) {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 753, 118);
        [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
    } else {

    }
}
```

Though the if statement is always true.

This is probably really obvious of what to do though I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `selectedSegmentIndex`, not `selected`.